# Native add-on compilation error in NODE_MODULE function on 12.0.0, works on 11.15.0

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon

I'm maintaining the [`aerospike`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aerospike) package, a client SDK for the Aerospike No-SQL database. On Node.js versions up to and including v11.15.0 this package compiles and works fine. But starting with v12.0.0 I'm getting a compile time error when building the native add-on, that I haven't been able to resolve.

The error occurs in this function (slightly abbreviated):

```cpp
void Aerospike(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module)
{
    AerospikeClient::Init();
    export("client", Nan::New<FunctionTemplate>(client)->GetFunction());
        // more exports
}

NODE_MODULE(aerospike, Aerospike)
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/aerospike/src/main/aerospike.o
../src/main/aerospike.cc:102:6: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
void Aerospike(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module)
     ^
../src/main/aerospike.cc:102:23: error: 'Object' does not refer to a value
void Aerospike(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module)
                      ^
/Users/jhecking/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3356:17: note: declared here
class V8_EXPORT Object : public Value {
                ^
../src/main/aerospike.cc:102:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Handle'
void Aerospike(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module)
               ^
../src/main/aerospike.cc:102:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'exports'
void Aerospike(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module)
                              ^
../src/main/aerospike.cc:102:47: error: 'Object' does not refer to a value
void Aerospike(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module)
                                              ^
/Users/jhecking/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3356:17: note: declared here
class V8_EXPORT Object : public Value {
                ^
../src/main/aerospike.cc:102:40: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Handle'
void Aerospike(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module)
                                       ^
../src/main/aerospike.cc:102:55: error: use of undeclared identifier 'module'
void Aerospike(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module)
                                                      ^
../src/main/aerospike.cc:102:62: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
void Aerospike(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module)
                                                             ^
                                                             ;
8 errors generated.
```

The module uses the older C++ add-on API, not n-api. I'm using the latest version nan v2.13.2.

The error can also be seen in this Travis CI job: https://travis-ci.org/aerospike/aerospike-client-nodejs/jobs/523788617.

The full source code is here: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-nodejs/blob/2b9554d1158abda58c17cfbd0438d78f0212ef9e/src/main/aerospike.cc#L102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct signature for the second arg of `NODE_MODULE` is `void InitializerFunction(Local<Object> exports[, Local<Value> module])` ([ref](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2976bbd68f936c4f96b6028219ceb9bfc4b84f22/src/node.h#L498)). `Handle` was removed from v8; it's replacement is `Local`.

If you're not upgrading to N-API, NAN is a good way to avoid these changes.